# ARM stack operations

Tags: assembly, arm

I have this ARM code, it's in little endian. I have problems with the lanes marked with a *

```
 AREA datos, DATA, READWRITE

resultado SPACE 4
pila SPACE 20
topPila

AREA prog, CODE, READONLY

ENTRY

ldr sp, =topPila
mov r0, #15
mov r1, #4
stmfd sp!, {r0, r1}

bl sbr_calculo

 ldmfd sp!, {r2}
 ldmfd sp!, {r0, r1}
 ldr r4, =resultado
 str r2, [r4]

b fin

sbr_calculo
 sub sp, sp, #4
 push {r5,r6,r7,lr} *
 ldr r5, [sp, #20] *
 ldr r6, [sp, #27] *
 mov r7, #0
 mov pc, lr

fin

END
```

And here is the memory adresses:

```
mem32[0x40000060] = 00 00 00 00
mem32[0x4000005C] = 04 00 00 00
mem32[0x40000058] = 0F 00 00 00
mem32[0x40000054] = 00 00 00 00
mem32[0x40000050] = 14 00 00 40
mem32[0x4000004C] = 00 00 00 00
mem32[0x40000048] = 00 00 00 00
mem32[0x40000044] = 48 00 00 40
```

1-When I execute the `push {r5,r6,r7,lr}`, the sp has the value `0x40000054`   and I don't undestand why the first value loaded is the lr value that is `0x40000014` and it doesn't load 4 words only 3 because in the `mem32[0x40000044]` I think there should be one value of the registers used in the push, but there is the 0x4000048, which is the value of label `resultado`.

2- Here is all ok, I load into r5 the value of the address sp + #20, which is the value of `mem32[0x4000005C]`, and r5 is 0x00000004

3- Here I load into r6 the value of address sp + #27, which is the value of `mem32[0x4000005F`, but I dont understand why r6 is `0x00000400`

Comment: it is all described in the arm documentation, what part of the documentation did you not understand?

Comment: @old_timer For example in the `push {r5,r6,r7,lr}` operation, why it starts storing the value of lr(r13). I mean is it following any order or something?

Comment: yes the order and address described in the arm documentation

Comment: @old_timer I think that I have found the answer. The lr is pushed at the start for not lose the return address in other subrutine calls. Is it correct?

Comment: look up the bl instruction and think about one function calling another function calling another function.

Comment: infocenter.arm.com  architectural reference manual, start with the armv5 one.

Comment: @old_timer Thanks, Im reading it. As I see, the push instruction with the lr is used to enter in a subroutine and for the exit, is used the pop instruction with the pc. Because if I start using push and after pop, Im leaving the stack the same as in the beginning. In my code I use `mov pc, lr` but I see that its deprecated. Is it correct?

Comment: you will see in the instruction that mov pc,lr does not change modes between arm and thumb where bx lr will.  mov pc, lr still works but if you want to mix arm and thumb code or as a good habit in case you ever do mix, return with bx lr, OR, some architecture versions you can pop the pc and it will properly handle switching between arm modes...so it depends on the architecture version of your chip, get the armv7 (not 8) architectural reference manual and look at those various instructions and their descriptions

Comment: push and pop are not real instructions they are ldm/stm instructions, check the encoding...the armv7 doc will show the variations between armv4 through armv7 for the ldm instruction or pop if they include that as a pseudo instruction.

Comment: @old_timer Thanks! But one last question, I see that for ARMv7 the load instruction supports unaligned acces, but in `ldr r6[sp, #27]`, I have the address `0x4000005F` that is word-unaligned, then I read I have to rotate it but dont know how many bits.

Comment: if it supports unaligned then you can do an unaligned access (it does if enabled).  But for a byte addressable address space (just about all that we deal with) a byte access is always aligned (ldrb,strb).  A halfword which in arm is 16 bits needs the least significant bit or bit 0 of the address to be a zero to be aligned (0x0,0x02,0x04,0x06)(ldrh/strh).  For a word, 32 bits, aligned means the least significant two bits bits 0 and bit 1 have to be zero to be aligned. (0x0,0x04,0x08,0x0c,0x10,0x14)(ldr/str).  you dont shift or rotate them you either add or subtract.

Comment: Ill give you the answer to an interview question we often ask.  align on a 4 byte boundary (addr = (addr+3)&(~3)).  Nobody ever gets it that cleanly now that aligns up to the next aligned address to align down everyone should get addr = addr & (~3).  simply remove the lower bits so 0x4000005C in your case.or 0x40000060 if moving up to the next aligned address depends on what you are doing.  And this all scales up, 64 bit alignment means lower 3 bits, 2 to the power 3 is 8 bytes is 64 bits.  128 bits, 16 bytes, two to the power 4, lower 4 bits have to be zero.

Comment: @old_timer I dont understand it very well, in my case i have `0x4000005F` and the lower bits are 1 so I have to take the word from addresses `5F to 5C`?

Comment: I dont understand what your question is about.  we went from push/pop which should always be aligned if the stack is used properly, to an unaligned access.  What is at 0x4000005F that you need to access as a word?  how did it get there and why are you accessing it that way, write it and read it aligned and you wont have this problem.

Comment: Well, the code at the beginning of the post is a posible exam question, where I have to write what is doing each instruction. The only thing that I dont understand is `ldr r6 [sp, #27]` because my sp in that moment is `x40000044` and the final addres is `0x4000005F`, and this address isnt word aligned. Then my question is having that address for loading a word into `r6`, have i to take the word from 5F to 5C? I did it with Keil uVision but dont understand the value loaded into r6

Comment: ahh okay, it isnt word aligned for some reason, but that doesnt mean you cant figure out what it is doing, sounds like you have you take the address of the specified register add 27 (decimal in this case), read a word from that location (little endian one would assume but that is just an assumption) and put the result in r6.  unaligned is unaligned, what are the four bytes starting at that address and what word does that result in?  if you find 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44 then r6 gets 0x44332211

Comment: @old_timer Yeah its little endian. My memory addresses with their values are at the beginning of the post. And the value that gets r6 is `0x00000400` but dont know why

Comment: Note, if you read the documentation you can temporarily change the data accesses to big endian (be8) on an armv7...thus the comment...so starting with 5c you have 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00...  so 0x5F is 0x04 right and the four bytes that follow you have shown take them and little endian them into a 32 bit number and you get?

Comment: @old_timer yeah, 0x5F is 0x04 but the 4 bytes that follow are all 0x00, that in 32 bit would be `0x00000000`. Dont see how I can get the result that Keil shows me

Comment: if you are doing a 32 bit ldr from address ...0x5F and the byte at 0x5F is 0x04, the byte at 0x60 is at 0x00, as well as 0x61, and 0x62 and 0x63 then your 32 bit number loaded from that address would be 0x00000004 if you are telling me all the correct information.

Comment: if 0x5C had 0x11223344 and 0x60 had 0x55667788 then a ldr from 0x5F would be 0x66778811.  (for cores after armv5 or armv6 one of those. certainly an armv7

Comment: @old_timer The result is 0x00000400, I'll revise the code because something must be wrong. Thanks for all! Now I understand much better all you have explained

Comment: that is within the realm of possibilities based on what you told me either you or me slipped a byte but I expected there to be a 0x04 and the rest zeros.

Comment: just to mess with your brain, on an armv4 you can do unaligned, you disable the fault trap, but it ROTATES the data within the word if 0x5C has 0x11223344 and 0x60 has 0x55667788 then an unaligned 0x5F access on an armv4 with the abort disabled should give 0x22334411 instead of 0x66778811 as one would expect